# Detect receiving token address in "receive() payable"

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, smart-contract-wallets

for the given receive function , is there a way I can detect the receiving tokens address (Detect what coin my contract is receiving )

is it possible to extract this information from **msg** ?

```
receive() payable external {
    balance += msg.value;
    emit TransferReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `receive` function is triggered by a transfer of the native token only, such as ETH on Ethereum or BNB on Binance Smart Chain.

Therefore, `msg.value` is always an amount of the native token and never an amount of any ERC-20 token.

Comment: How can I achieve this behavior with an ERC20 token? I want to know when a smart contract I created receives a USDC transfer.

Comment: @tlalco You can't. An ERC20 transfer happens when an address calls the ERC20 contract. Your contract has no way of knowing that this ERC20 contract was called.